TypeScript & narrowing union types when using built-in methods in OpenLayers 9.1
I get a lot of typescript errors while trying to use methods on types like StyleLike in OpenLayers 9.1. In this example, I create a layer with a single point feature and let it use the default styles:
const feat = new Feature({
    geometry: new Point ([0, 0]),
    name: 'Whatever',
    population: 100,
    rain: 500
})

const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    features: [feat]
})

const pointLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: vectorSource
})

If I later want to get the color of the features:
const color = pointLayer.getStyle()
console.log(color.getFill().getColor())

The variable color is inferred by typescript to be StyleLike | null | undefined type.
StyleLike is defined as Style | Style[] | StyleFunction according to the documentation.
The console.log line will produce a red squiggly under getFill() saying:
Property 'getFill' does not exist on type 'StyleLike'.
  Property 'getFill' does not exist on type 'Style[]'.

This makes sense because yes, if color were of Style[] it would not have a getFill() method, but in this example, I know color is really of Style type (I have also confirmed this while debugging). The Style type has a valid getFill() method. The code does run and I do get the value I want, but how do I properly define the type of color so I don't get error squigglies?
Defining color: Style is not valid. It will put a squiggle under color and say:
Type 'StyleLike | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Style'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Style'.


Possibly you write if (color && ("getFill" in color)) before color.getFill().getColoer() it will work, but right now this isn't a [mre] we can use to test it ourselves. Please [edit] the code to be a self-contained example that either does not depend on third-party libraries, or imports them for us.

Assuming I got the imports right, this playground link shows the two general approaches; either you do thing safely and perform checks to convince TS that you're right about what you "know" color to be, or you just assert that what you know is true and deal with any runtime problems yourself. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer (or find a suitable duplicate target). If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz - that works, I was just hoping there was a more Typescripty solution rather than having to do a bunch of if statements everywhere. But if that's how it has to be, then that's how it has to be. Thanks!

I showed two ways of doing it. One was if statements, the other was type assertions. Did you miss it?

I saw it, but I prefer more safe approaches. Appreciate your answer, feel free to write it up for me to approve.

Given that the TypeScript typings for color include the possibility that it might be null or undefined or an array or a function, you should double check how you "know" that color is actually  a Style. Debugging is a good sign, but it might be that the same code could have different results if run in a different environment.  I'm not sure because I know nothing about OpenLayers.
Anyway, there are two general approaches, depending on how sure you are that you know what will happen at runtime when you write color.getFill().getColor().

If you're not really sure that color will definitely be a Style, you could write code that checks and convinces TypeScript that what you're doing is type safe.  For example:
if (color && "getFill" in color) {
    const fill = color.getFill();
    if (fill) {
        console.log(fill.getColor())
    }
}

Here we narrow color to Style by truthiness checking (to eliminate null and undefined) and by in operator narrowing (to ensure it's Style and not the array or function).  We also have to check color.getFill() for truthiness since it is also supposedly possibly null.
This is type safe but somewhat tedious, as you need to keep checking things, some of which require to to copy things to other variables.  (If all you had to do was avoid null and undefined you could use optional chaining like color?.getFill()?.getColor(), but the array/function thing prevents it from being that simple.)

On the other hand, if you are sure about color and don't want to bother with extra runtime checks, you can just assert what you know:
console.log((color as Style).getFill()!.getColor())

Here color as Style is a type assertion saying that you vouch for the fact that color can safely be treated as a Style.  I've also used the non-null assertion operator (!) on the results of getFill() to tell the compiler that you know it's not null.  This doesn't change the runtime code at all, and it prevents the compiler errors. If you're right about the type of color and the truthiness of its getFill() result, then this is fine. If you're wrong, you'll get runtime errors. If that possibility is unlikely enough for you to worry about, then asserting the types is perfectly reasonable.

Whether or not you want to do runtime checks or skip them depends on your use case and requirements.
Playground link to code
